# PCSC Lite smartcard names

Tags: linux, smartcard, pcsc

In windows we have function SCardListCards
but I'm programming under Linux with pcsclite, how is possible to list cards here?
Card names, attributes ?

Comment: @utility opensc, pcsclite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just request to internal windows Database with known smartcards ATR and ATRMask. 
You can look at this database: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards`